# Graph Theory: A loop-free connected graph with degree sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**- Background Information:**

> I am studying graph theory in discrete mathematics. As I was practicing questions I came across this solution, provided by my professor, which is confusing for me to fully understand it. I need some clarification for the solution to make sense

---

**- Question and Solution:**

> Construct a graph with the specified properties. If no such graphs exist, explain why.

[image]

---

**- My question:**

Could you please explain...

> 1. Why can we have a maximum of 2 nodes of degree 1? In the degree sequence, there are 3 nodes of degree 1, so I don't understand where the 2 is coming from.
> 2. Why does the graph not exist? If we add the degree sequences, we get a sum of 24 which is even and acceptable for drawing the graph.

---

- Edit: [definitions]

> A loop is an edge from a vertex to itself.

Comment: What does "loop free" mean in this problem? I can think of two different interpretations, but perhaps you can just define it for us.

Comment: Hi @LeeMosher, I provided the definition above.

Comment: That's an odd definition... I was expecting that a loop indicates either an edge both of whose endpoints are at the same node, i.e. a cycle of 1 vertex and 1 edge, or perhaps a more general kind of loop which is a cycle of $k$ vertices and $k$ edges for some $k \ge 1$.

Comment: I meant a loop with edge{x,x}, so the edge goes back to itself.

Comment: Alright, that's what I would call a cycle of $1$ vertex and $1$ edge. But I definitely would *not* say it is an isolated vertex with no incident edge; instead I might say that the vertex $x$ is *doubly incident* to that loop edge.

Comment: Sure, I would like to learn, so I take your suggestion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a node of degree $7$ that is joined to all the other nodes. Now consider the node of degree $5$ ... how many nodes of degree $1$ are now possible ?

[image]

Comment: People always say there is something about visual learning that makes it special, now I fully understand it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6):

The degree $7$ node, which I'll denote $v_1$, connects to *all $8-1=7$ other nodes*.

One of those must be the degree $5$ node, which I'll denote $v_2$, and $v_2$ connects to $5$ other nodes distinct from $v_2$, *at most $1$* of which can be $v_1$ itself.

So, *at least $4$* of the nodes that $v_2$ connects to are also nodes that $v_1$ connects to, and these nodes all therefore have valence $\ge 2$.

Of the seven nodes that $v_1$ connects to, one of them is $v_2$ which has valence $4$, and we've shown that at least $4$ others of them have valence $\ge 2$. That leaves at most $2$ which have valence $1$.

Comment: Thank you sir, great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I think if I answer your first question, second one will be answered automatically.

Suppose for a contradiction that given graph exists. Then since one vertex out of eight has degree $7$, this vertex is connected all other vertices. Now, consider the vertex with degree $5$, which has one edge connected to the vertex with degree $7$. Also notice that remaining four edges must be connected to a vertex. But this is impossible since we already have $3$ vertices with degree $1$ and connected to the vertex with degree $7$, which is a contradiction as required (you can find the reason why we must have two vertices with degree $1$, of course without making the sum of degrees odd).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation my friend, it was really helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true unless the graph is free of multiple edges as well.

[image]

This is true for simple graphs as shown by other answers.